# socket.io : event disconnect when app android not connect to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I building a service use socket.io. Client web run on chrome connect to socket, when close chrome or internet, event socket.on('disconnect',function(){}) run but client is application android, event socket.on('disconnect', function(){}) not run when close app. Why? Thanks all!